# Xamarin - update current tab fragment in viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have 3 Fragments in a `viewPager`. Each fragment class has its own method to update fragment's views (for example, in TabFragment1.cs):

```
public void UpdateContent(View v)
    {

        // Sample values to read
        string locationCode = "528454";

        // Mapping views
        TextView tv_currentConditions = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentConditions);
        TextView tv_currentTemperature = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentTemperature);
        TextView tv_currentRealFeel = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.currentRealFeel);
        TextView tv_minMaxTemperature = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.minMaxTemperature);

        // Update view from database
        tv_currentConditions.Text = Sql.ReadValue(locationCode,"currentConditions");
        tv_currentTemperature.Text = Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "currentTemperature") + "°C";
        tv_currentRealFeel.Text = GetString(Resource.String.feelLike) + " " + Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "currentRealFeel") + "°C";
        tv_minMaxTemperature.Text = Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "minTemperature") + " " + Sql.ReadValue(locationCode, "maxTemperature") + "°C";

    }
```

The challenge is: to define which fragment tab is selected now and launch the method from active fragment class.

UPD: I know, how to get current tab number:

```
    public int currentTabNum;

    void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
    {
        var adapter = new Adapter(SupportFragmentManager);
        adapter.AddFragment(new tabFragment1(), GetString(Resource.String.tab1));
        adapter.AddFragment(new tabFragment2(), GetString(Resource.String.tab2));
        adapter.AddFragment(new tabFragment3(), GetString(Resource.String.tab3));
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        viewPager.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.PageSelected += (object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e) => {
            //Snackbar.Make(drawerLayout, e.Position.ToString(), Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
            currentTabNum = e.Position;
        };
    }

    class Adapter: Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
        List<string> fragmentTitles = new List<string>();
        public Adapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm) { }
        public void AddFragment(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment, String title)
        {
            fragments.Add(fragment);
            fragmentTitles.Add(title);
        }
        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return fragments.Count;
            }
        }
        public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(fragmentTitles[position]);
        }
    }
```

So, the question: how to send from intentService from its onDesroy() method, a command to mainActivity to update current tab?

Comment: What's you mean " send from IntentService from its onDesroy() method" ?

Comment: York Shen, my activity sends several intents to intent service. For example, "put weather for City1 into database", "put weather for City2 into database" and so on. After intent service completes all the jobs, it calls OnDestroy() and stops. I want intent service to tell the activity to update views of current tab fragment with new data . So, I've found how an Activity can define currently selected tab fragment, and have a methods for each of tab fragments to update it's views. So, the only thing I need is a way to let Activity immediately  know that intent service has finished the work.

Comment: When your  IntentService completes all the jobs you could send a broadcast to Activity, once your Activity received message then you can update your user interface.